# Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop -- but they already do (two children per iteration)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

This question is unlike similar ones because as far as I can tell, all other questions of this nature really do not have unique keys for all children being `map`'d.

Here is my code...

First, for good measure, I have this check, so there can be no doubt that each key is unique:

```
    const nbItems = items.length
    const nbUniqueUuids = new Set(items.map((item) => item.uuid)).size
    if (nbItems !== nbUniqueUuids) {
        throw new Error("Non-unique UUIDs detected")
    }
```

Then, I do this in the return statement of the component:

```
{items.map((item, index) => {
                return (
                    <>
                        {index !== 0 && (
                            <Xarrow
                                key={`${item.uuid}-arrow`}
                                start={item.uuid}
                                end={items[index - 1].uuid}
                            />
                        )}
                        <Item
                            key={item.uuid}
                            action={item}
                        />
                    </>
                )
            })}
```

As you can see, two elements are rendered: An `Xarrow` and an `Item`. However, each has its own key: one with a `-arrow` suffix, and one without. The `uuid` property is confirmed unique, or the if-statement would have triggered and thrown an error.

Why does React think there's a non-unique child here, when clearly, each child has a unique `key`?

The exact error message is: `Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop. Check the render method of MyExampleComponent.` "MyExampleComponent" here is confirmed to be this one. Neither `Xarrow` nor `Item` render any children.

If I wrap both items in a `div` and give *it* the `key`, it works, but I don't want to do that.

I will also note that this works as it should, but I still get the error in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I have to give the `key` to the fragment (`<></>`), and in order to do that, I have to use the full fragment syntax: `<React.Fragment key={item.uuid}>...</React.Fragment>`